# I am looking for a way to protect myself from a possible evil maid attack

Tags: security, boot-loader

I found a way that you can move the boot loader to a USB. Then in case of any changes I thought about checking hash of the USB after boot. Since hard drive will be encrypted, an evil maid can't know which file contains the hash. Or I can just write the hash to a paper.

What I wonder is, can't the evil maid script on the boot loader basically revert the changes on the USB? So hash will be same but the keylogger script will be loaded and maybe will save itself to the hard drive? This is probably an unrealistic thing to happen but still would be a flaw.

What are the ways to make this not possible other than carrying the USB in your pocket all the time?

Update: I found a tool that you can permanently lock the write protection for SD cards. I will test it if it doesn't work i will just try to modify the SD card after putting the boot loader.

https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool

Comment: If you can carry the USB around with you always then this is not really an evil maid situation where the idea is that you leave the machine unattended for a significant amount of time.

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/538/

Comment: @icarus not entirely correct.  If someone can gain access to the USB stick (a pick pocket) then the risk still remains the same.  Breaking the hardware into pieces (using a USB stick) makes the evil maid attack more tricky but not impossible.

Comment: @PhilipCouling If a pickpocket gains access to the USB stick then the OP is not carrying it always unless the attack takes place inside the pocket. If the attack is done inside the pocket whilst it is being carried then it is not unattended.

Comment: @icarus entirely incorrect. As long as the USB stick is both stolen **and returned**; with or without the knowledge of the owner, there is opportunity *"...excuse me sir, you dropped this..."*.  Arguably this is easier with a USB because it doesn't require dismantling to perform the attack where a laptop might.  Very few of us keep our keys in our pocket at all times. None of us are conscious 24x7x365.  A pickpocket / return scenario is just one possible example but there are many.

Comment: @PhilipCouling The text of the question says "What are the ways to make this not possible other than carrying the USB in your pocket all the time?" This rules out taking and returning. If you want to argue that it is not realistic to keep the usb drive on you all the time then fine, but that is a different question.

Comment: @icarus you appear to have misunderstood the meaning for that sentence.  Apologies if English isn't your first language.  That sentence means the OP is looking for a solution that is **not** carrying a USB  at all times.  The phase "other than" infers *alternative solutions* or "solutions that are not this solution".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evil maid attacks are particularly hard to counter.  That's why physical security is always important as well as software security.

In the most extreme scenarios, someone could replace your entire machine with a duplicate and log / transmit enough key strokes to gain access to your real machine before you realized.  These scenarios end up rather fanciful (https://www.xkcd.com/538/).  Its worth understanding that that as a home or commercial user there is balanced advice available.  **If you are a government official carrying top secret documents then perhaps "balanced" advice isn't for you.**

---

Going with the Wikipedia definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_maid_attack

> An evil maid attack is an attack on an unattended device, in which an attacker with physical access alters it in some undetectable way so that they can later access the device, or the data on it.
>
> The name refers to the scenario where a maid could subvert a device left unattended in a hotel room – but the concept itself also applies to situations such as a device being intercepted while in transit, or taken away temporarily by airport or law enforcement personnel.

---

## What can you do about it?

Your first line of defense should be to correctly configure and a [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module).  Correct use of your system's TPM should fend off the casual attacker because in general they won't just be able to replace your operating system with an "evil" one.  Your HD encryption keys should be stored in the TPM, and the TPM should never disclose these to un-trusted (un-signed) operating system.

I'll avoid explaining how to do this in full because there are options and it may require some research for your system.  I will however draw your attention to a couple of links:

- https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot
- https://threat.tevora.com/secure-boot-tpm-2/

---

### Why are TPM's not entirely safe?

The most difficult issue to overcome is that someone could install some hardware between your RAM and your motherboard and read encryption keys right out of memory.  It's not likely that the average attacker will have this kind of technology but if you're carrying government secrets across borders then all bets are off.

Assuming that the hardware has not been tampered with, there is still another vector of attack based solely on modifying the software:  **You**

Imagine two scenarios:

#### Scenario 1

- You switch on your laptop and find it won't boot.
- You investigate and find something has got corrupted on the HD and the TPM is refusing to give you the key to decrypt your hard drive
- You dutifully type in your [backup decryption password](https://www.lisenet.com/2013/luks-add-keys-backup-and-restore-volume-header/)
- You reset your TPM and get things working normally.

#### Scenario 2

- An evil maid replaces your OS with an evil one
- When you switch on the find it (the fake) won't boot.
- You investigate and find the TPM is refusing to decrypt the hard drive
- You dutifully type in your backup decryption password.
- You reset your TPM and get it to accept the fake as your OS proper (oops)

Notice that the weak link with the TPM and an evil maid attack is **you**.  **It's important to understand that if something goes wrong then you must not boot your laptop, but instead recover it via a separate machine and carefully investigate what went wrong.**

---

If you really want to protect against this (we're getting back to https://www.xkcd.com/538/ here) you might consider a system where:

- You type your first secret password
- Your laptop response with something secret only accessible with your first password.
- You type your second secret password

Only this way can you be comfortable (in a balanced way, not a [tin foil hat way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil_hat)) that your computer was not compromised before you type in your [second] password.

The second password here might be [two factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication).

Comment: Hi, Philip. If understood correctly your last scheme with two secret passwords, it is vulnerable if an evil made can access the computer two times. The first time, an evil made disables Secure Boot and installs an OS that obtains the first secret password from the user, sends it to the evil made, reverts SSD to the previous state, enables Secure Boot, and reboots the computer. The second time, the evil made types the first secret password, read the computer's response, installs an OS that shows the response, obtains the second secret password from the user, and sends it to the evil made.

Comment: Yes. That's right. The protection against this however is that you (the owner) have been alerted to the first attack: the machine didn't respond correctly to the first password, it just rebooted.  If you recognises this then you should immediately take steps to rebuild your system and change both passwords. If you don't recognise your system misbehaved then we are back to scenario 2 above and your system gets compromised.

Comment: @beroal in short these attacks are as much tricking the user as hacking the system. If the user doesn't recognise the hack then no amount of technology will save them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the UEFI to only **boot** from the internal drive.
2. Protect the UEFI with a good enough **password**. A six digit PIN would be good enough.
3. Paste a **tamper evident seal** on the computer case. The hardest to imitate the seal, and the more self evident its function is to the user, the more secured the computer would be.

[image]